# Why would I see PHP NOTICE and ERRORs when running a script as a regular user, but not as root?

Tags: php

As far as I can tell, there's no difference between the error reporting or message redirection between users.  They both use the same PHP ini.

However, when I run a script as a regular user, I get tons of NOTICES, when run as root, I get none.  When starting PHP interactive mode as a regular user, I get two PHP Warnings that 'memcache' and 'xmlwriter' are already loaded;  when starting as the root user, I get no warnings.

I know that I should be fixing the warnings, not "making the warnings go away;"  that's on the ticket.  The question is, Why are the users treated differently?  Why does a regular user get notices and warnings, but root does not, even if their error reporting are the same?

Comment: Are the environments identical for the two users?

Comment: The environments are exactly identical:

$ php Script.php
$ su -
# php Script.php

I get error messages the first time, but no error messages after switching user to root.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the actual PHP binary that you're executing is different due to differences in your `$PATH`. You may have a copy of PHP installed in `/usr/bin` that uses shared modules for memcache, and another in `/usr/local/bin` that has it statically linked.

Both executables may reference `/etc/php.ini` for their configuration. If the configuration file is telling PHP to try to load a shared module, the copy that has it statically linked will generate the errors you're getting.

Try the command `which php` as the normal user and root, which should report back the location of the PHP executable. You can also say `echo $PATH` as each user to see the directories it's searching. You may need to add/remove a directory from the `$PATH`, which you should be able to do in your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked this and it appears that they are using the same binary, and neither have any differences in ~/.profile.

Thanks for your efforts;  at this point I'm just going to assume "that's the way PHP does it," that PHP suppresses warnings for root that make it through for regular users.  I can duplicate the effect by changing the bitflags in the error_reporting variable.

Answer (score 0):

Something is different in the environment.

What if you try investigating like this:

```
$ php -i > mortal
$ su php -i > root
$ diff mortal root
```